# Why is my "H" Drive Marked as Active in Disk Manager?

Tags: partitioning, disk-management

In my understanding "Active Partition" is the one that indicates to MBR that it's the one to boot from. Am I wrong? Here's how it looks like in Disk Manager in Windows 7:

[image]

My question is why "H" (previously D drive) is marked as active? I wanted to deleted it but I am worrying if it's something to do with drive C. BitLocker was previously installed on it but here are the files that it has:

[image]

'tcpserver.exe' and 'Temp' folder are just data I moved there and it's not system data. I am wondering whether it's safe to delete that partition. My goal is to extend partition of drive C without using 3rd party tools. As long as I delete drive H I can create free space that's adjacent to drive H and continuous. This will make it possible to extend drive C. Thanks.

Comment: You need that particular partition due to the Boot folder. If you delete that partition you will be unable to boot into Windows.

Answer (score -1):

There's clearly a `boot` folder, hinting at an installation of Windows' boot loader. We can't tell whether it's in use though.

However, this is pretty easy to test, assuming it's not just another partition on your main hard disk.

Turn off your PC and disconnect the drive's data cable. Then try booting up. If it works, you don't need it. If it doesn't, it's the current boot manager that's actually in use and you'd have to move/reinstall it first (not the whole OS).

Comment: The author has a single physical drive.  Your suggestion is confusing.  I know for a fact that is the case.  It also is sort of obvious from the screenshot supplied.  How I know is because of a discussion in the chat room.

Comment: @Ramhound But the Disk Manager screenshot (not sure it's been there before) shows three primary partitions?